# Div positioning based on clicked element in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if it's possible to position a `div` based on which element in a table is clicked. I have a grid of images in my code and if an image is clicked I want a speechballoon to popup next to the image, giving the user options to do some stuff with the images.

I currently have this (although with more images):

```
<div id="edit" class="popup"><center><p>Edit | Share | Delete</p></center></div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img id="image1" class="image" src="01.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="image2" class="image" src="02.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="image3" class="image" src="03.png"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and Javascript:

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#edit").fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: That's excellent! That's just the way to do it. Where exactly are you finding the difficulty?

Comment: Well, the problem is how do I place the speechballoon hovering over the right image. Now it just hovers in the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you're using jQuery, I'd suggest using the `offset` function (https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

you'll need to set edit's position to absolute, with CSS:

```
#edit{
        position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var offset = $(this).offset(); //get the clicked element's position
    offset.top += $(this).height(); // add the height, because we want the bubble
                                    // to be directly below
    $("#edit").offset(offset); //set 'edit's offset
    $("#edit").fadeIn();
});
```

check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/h4FXb/

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your suggested code or mine, but it keeps floating on the top of the table. No matter which image I click. (I have three images in a row in my table).

Comment: I.. hmm.. I made an edit for a needed CSS you might not have, but it should've worked anyway. Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it out. The problem was that I had it like this: `<li><a><img/></a></li>` ?